# Integrar navbar de tema wordpress a mí codigo

Tags: html, css, wordpress

He creado un tema hijo del tema: twenty twenty-four, con los archivos correspondientes. El tema hijo funciona correctamente. Así que cree un archivo front-page.php en el que desde 0 cree el home de la página. Y la idea es integrar el nav y el footer del tema padre. Lo intenté y al actualizar el sitio el navbar como lista. Osea que toma los datos correctamente, pero el estilo por alguna razón no funciona.

Este es el sitio web: olimpiahome.com.mx

y este es el código de front-page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>">
     <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- resto del código -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que te dice la consola? Carga varios CSS así que no puedo ver el CSS del menú. Seguro que logras llegar al archivo CSS correctamente??

Comment: claro yo cree un archivo de estilos que es el que hay que crear para que el tema hijo pueda verse correctamente y allí añadi mis estilos: /*
Theme Name: Twenty Twenty-Four-Child
Version: 1.0
Description: A child theme of Twenty Twenty-Four
Author: olimpiahome.com.mx
Template: twentytwentyfour
*/


@import url("../twentytwentyfour/style.css"); y después mis estilos

Comment: psa q es un block theme, tenes q encolar el style del child via `functions.php` y mepa que declarar algunas cosas en el `theme.json`

Comment: La estructura es incorrecta, ahi estas agregando dos headers, un page solo debe tener un header y footer dentro de esos archivos poner sus respectivos headers y footer, tambien revisa la consola y ver que los css no esten dando 404 errors